# MongoDB Aggregations - Divide data into time buckets

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping, bucket

So I have some data which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ba41d8c5f60a647fc792c28",
        "key": "CPU Usage",
        "signaler": "lookup",
        "time": "2018-09-20T22:22:04.515Z",
        "status": "alarm"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ba41d8c5f60a647fc792c2a",
        "key": "NETWORK Usage",
        "signaler": "engine",
        "time": "2018-09-20T22:22:04.516Z",
        "status": "warning"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ba41d8c5f60a647fc792c29",
        "key": "NETWORK Usage",
        "signaler": "engine",
        "time": "2018-09-09T22:22:04.516Z",
        "status": "alarm"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ba41d8c5f60a647fc792c2d",
        "key": "CPU Usage",
        "signaler": "evaluator",
        "time": "2018-09-09T22:22:04.840Z",
        "status": "alarm"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ba41d8c5f60a647fc792c2b",
        "key": "RAM Usage",
        "signaler": "engine",
        "time": "2018-09-01T22:22:04.840Z",
        "status": "alarm"
    }
]
```

`key` and `signaler` can be any strings, `status` must be one of `alarm`, `warning` or `normal`.

I want to write an aggregation which groups on `signaler` + `key` and tells me the total alarms and warnings for 3 durations: all time, last week and last month.

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "signaler": "lookup",
            "key": "CPU Usage"
        },
        "alarmsWeek": 1,
        "warningsWeek": 0,
        "alarmsMonth": 1,
        "warningsMonth": 0,
        "alarmsAllTime": 1,
        "warningsAllTime": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "signaler": "engine",
            "key": "Network Usage"
        },
        "alarmsWeek": 0,
        "warningsWeek": 1,
        "alarmsMonth": 1,
        "warningsMonth": 1,
        "alarmsAllTime": 1,
        "warningsAllTime": 1       
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "signaler": "evaluator",
            "key": "CPU Usage"
        },
        "alarmsWeek": 0,
        "warningsWeek": 0,
        "alarmsMonth": 1,
        "warningsMonth": 0,
        "alarmsAllTime": 1,
        "warningsAllTime": 0       
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "signaler": "engine",
            "key": "RAM Usage"
        },
        "alarmsWeek": 0,
        "warningsWeek": 0,
        "alarmsMonth": 0,
        "warningsMonth": 0,
        "alarmsAllTime": 1,
        "warningsAllTime": 0       
    }
]
```

I know how to write the group stage which calculates the warnings and alarms for all time but I'm not sure how to do the time bucketing, especially since they are 'stacked' i.e the counts of last week will also be in the counts for last month.

The group step as far I understand:

```
[
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": { 
                "signaler":"$signaler",
                "key": "$key"

            }, 
            "totalWarnings": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {"$eq": [ "warning", "$level" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                } 
            }, 
            "totalAlarms": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        {"$eq": [ "alarm", "$level" ] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                } 
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        "$project": { 
            "_id": { "$concat": ["$_id.key", "+", "$_id.signaler"] },
            "key": "$_id.key",
            "signaler": "$_id.signaler",
            "totalAlarms": 1,
            "totalWarnings": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: can you provide a set of samples to test grouping plz?

Comment: Added more sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate Fanamy's answer, here's the group stage used to achieve this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "signaler": "$signaler", "key": "$key" },
    "alarmsWeek": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$and": [
              { "$eq": ["$status", "alarm"] },
              { "$lt": ["$time", { "$subtract": [new Date(), { "$multiply": [1000, 3600, 24, 7] }] }] }
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "warningsWeek": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$and": [
              { "$eq": ["$status", "warning"] },
              { "$lt": ["$time", { "$subtract": [new Date(), { "$multiply": [1000, 3600, 24, 7] }] }] }
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "alarmsMonth": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$and": [
              { "$eq": ["$status", "alarm"] },
              { "$lt": ["$time", { "$subtract": [new Date(), { "$multiply": [1000, 3600, 24, 30] }] }] }
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "warningsMonth": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$and": [
              { "$eq": ["$status", "warning"] },
              { "$lt": ["$time", { "$subtract": [new Date(), { "$multiply": [1000, 3600, 24, 30] }] }] }
            ]
          },
          "then": 1,
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "alarmsAllTime": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": { "if": { "$eq": ["$status", "alarm"] }, "then": 1, "else": 0 }}
    },
    "warningsAllTime": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": { "if": { "$eq": ["$status", "warning"] }, "then": 1, "else": 0 }}
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Should it not be `$gt` instead of `$lt`? i.e the doc's date should be greater than some date 1 week ago

Answer (score 0):

for the time buckets you could use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/ in combination with $subtract (as it supports dates) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/

so simply take the current Date, subtract 7 days or 30 for a month (it wouldn't be really "month-correct") and check if the date of the document is lower than your created date.